# GStreamer overlay graphics

Tags: graphics, gtk, streaming, gstreamer, broadcast

How would I be able to add live "broadcast" graphics on top of a gstreamer video. By broadcast I think of something like a scoreboard or news. It would be cool if there was some way of drawing html on top of it, since this would allow some simple animations using CSS and maybe javascript.

The key requirement though is the ability to manipulate graphics overlayed a video, while it is playing live. Therefore it would be ideal if the graphics didn't have to be pre-rendered with text for say each player.

Currently my application is written in GTK C and gstreamer, and I have been looking at achieving something with Cairo and `cairooverlay`.

I have also been looking at [this concept](https://blog.michael.franzl.name/2018/04/14/html5-javascript-css3-alpha-aware-video-overlays-on-top-of-live-gstreamer-video-pipelines/), but I am not sure if this will work with GTK.

Comment: Have you tried the [GtkOverlay](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkOverlay.html) container? It's used to overlay different widgets.

Comment: That's an interesting idea and probably good enough for now. Ideally though the graphics should also integrate with the gstreamer stream, so that it can be sent somewhere else.

Comment: Right. As there are multiple overlay plugins is gstreamer, you'd probably get best served by asking about possible approaches in one of their mailing lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Gtk solution on github https://github.com/Kalyzee/gst-webkit.

First compile & install as described in docs. To test it I just needed to add "enabled=1" to the test command line to make it work.

`GST_DEBUG=*webkit*:5 gst-launch-1.0 webkitsrc enabled=1 url="https://www.google.com/" ! video/x-raw, format=RGBA, framerate=25/1, width=1280, height=720 ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink sync=FALSE`

(Note: on Ubuntu 16.04 I needed to install  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev. For some reason libwebkit-dev was not sufficent)

Comment: thank you very much! This looks very promising. For now this will be the best answer and actually exactly what I was looking for - a gstreamer plugin with html support.

Comment: Looking at the source code I can see that it is exactly what I have been trying to achieve using webkitgtk and cairo. Can only find that a little amusing and nice to know.

Answer (score 1):

This post named [Web overlay in GStreamer with WPEWebKit](https://base-art.net/Articles/web-overlay-in-gstreamer-with-wpewebkit/) may be of interest. It's based on the [GStreamer for cloud-based live video handling](https://gstconf.ubicast.tv/videos/gstreamer-for-cloud-based-live-video-handling/) presentation from the BBC that shows a video played with some web overlaid notifications (second demo). Therefore using Webkit and GStreamer with web-based overlay seems doable.